# eBay API - unable to add Global Shipping Program option AddItemRequest

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, ebay-api

I have code that looks like this to create a XML Request.  I've tried a few variations, but only get errors. Can anyone help?

```
// create the XML request
$xmlRequest  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
$xmlRequest .= "<AddItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">";
$xmlRequest .= "<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>";
$xmlRequest .= "<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Item>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Title>" . $addTitle . "</Title>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Description>" . $addDesc . "</Description>";
$xmlRequest .= "<PrimaryCategory>";
$xmlRequest .= "<CategoryID>" . $addCatID . "</CategoryID>";
$xmlRequest .= "</PrimaryCategory>";
$xmlRequest .= "<StartPrice>" . $addSPrice . "</StartPrice>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>";
$xmlRequest .= "<CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Country>US</Country>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Currency>USD</Currency>";
$xmlRequest .= "<DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>";
$xmlRequest .= "<PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>";
$xmlRequest .= "<PayPalEmailAddress>yourpaypal@emailaddress.com</PayPalEmailAddress>";
$xmlRequest .= "<PictureDetails>";
$xmlRequest .= "<PictureURL>" . $addPicture . "</PictureURL>";
$xmlRequest .= "</PictureDetails>";
$xmlRequest .= "<PostalCode>05485</PostalCode>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Quantity>1</Quantity>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ReturnPolicy>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>";
$xmlRequest .= "<RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Description>" . $addDesc . "</Description>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>";
$xmlRequest .= "</ReturnPolicy>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingDetails>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingServiceOptions>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>";
$xmlRequest .= "</ShippingServiceOptions>";
$xmlRequest .= "</ShippingDetails>";
$xmlRequest .= "<Site>US</Site>";
$xmlRequest .= "<UUID>" . $uuid . "</UUID>";
$xmlRequest .= "</Item>";
$xmlRequest .= "<RequesterCredentials>";
$xmlRequest .= "<eBayAuthToken>" . AUTH_TOKEN . "</eBayAuthToken>";
$xmlRequest .= "</RequesterCredentials>";
$xmlRequest .= "<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>";
$xmlRequest .= "</AddItemRequest>";
```

I'm thinking it would be something like this, but this didn't work.

```
<GlobalShippingEnabled>1</GlobalShippingEnabled>
```

Comment: Circumventing the rules by stuffing your post with a bunch of profane railing against the site you're trying to post to? Great idea.

Answer (score 1):

The field is [GlobalShipping](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#Request.Item.ShippingDetails.GlobalShipping) and needs to appear within the ShippingDetails element.

```
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingDetails>";
$xmlRequest .= "<GlobalShipping>1</GlobalShipping>";
    .
    . Rest of your shipping details.
    .
$xmlRequest .= "</ShippingDetails>";
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me pop it in and try it.